# Using PROJ C++ API for CRS-to-CRS transformations

Tags: c++, proj, pyproj

[pyproj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj) is a language binding for [PROJ](https://proj.org/index.html). The **pyproj** module provides easy-to-use methods for CRS-to-CRS transformations, For instance, use it to convert global latitude/longitude (degrees) to local coordinates with respect to some coordinate reference system (metres):

```
>>> from pyproj import Transformer
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 6677)
>>> transformer.transform(35.9032597, 139.9343755)
(-10728.330840296036, 9120.537451921156)
```

**PROJ** provides a [C++ API](https://proj.org/development/reference/cpp/index.html) but the documentation is pure crap. There are no sample codes and I couldn't find my way through it.
I'd be really appreciative if anyone could give a clue on how to use the C++ API the same way **pyproj** works for arbitrary transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
#include <proj.h>
#include <iostream>

PJ_CONTEXT *C;
PJ *P;

C = proj_context_create();

P = proj_create_crs_to_crs(C, "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:6677", NULL);

PJ_COORD input_coords,
         output_coords; // https://proj.org/development/reference/datatypes.html#c.PJ_COORD

input_coords = proj_coord(35.9032597, 139.9343755, 0, 0);

output_coords = proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, input_coords);

std::cout << output_coords.xy.x << " " << output_coords.xy.y << std::endl;

/* Clean up */
proj_destroy(P);
proj_context_destroy(C); // may be omitted in the single threaded case
```

Of course, beyond this initial level, you can make whatever function or class wrappers you need. But this reproduces the pyproj example you posted.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. You meant <iostream> instead of <stdio.h>, eh? Also, I thought I'd get something more CPP-ish, because this one uses the C APIs I guess.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, iostream. I'm not sure what you mean about making it more cpp-ish. As I said, you will probably want to wrap it up in a class or a function depending on what makes sense for your project. You could throw in some autos, make some unique pointers, or whatever else works.

Comment: Hi @AndrewHolmgren I tried your example and getting this error `undefined symbol: proj_context_create` , Would you please help thanks

Comment: Hi @AliAkram, you're likely not linking the library when you compile. Since I don't know what system you're on and since there are so many ways to compile across different systems, I can't give you an exact answer.

Comment: Hi @AliAkram. That is a linker problem. On an Ubuntu 22.04 with the g++ compiler I used `g++ sample.cpp -o sample -lproj`. You need to link against the PROJ library.

Comment: Basically I need to compile proj for android which have 4 architectures like below armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64

Comment: it return me same value what i send to it i.e 35.9032597, 139.9343755